# Modify LaTeX transcription of code in Sage

Tags: sage

I would like to modify the function `latex()` in Sage: is there a way to choose how a list a symbols should be translated in TeX? In my particular case, I would like the matrices to be coded with 'matrix' rather than with `array`, of even better, with a personalised macro in latex allowing one to have the entries of the matrix in displaystyle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two answers to this.  One type of customization is easy and documented, e.g. if you do

```
latex.matrix_delimiters?
```

the documentation gives you

```
sage: a = matrix(1, 1, [17])
sage: latex.matrix_delimiters("[", "]")
sage: latex(a)
\left[\begin{array}{r}
17
\end{array}\right]
```

There is a similar `latex.matrix_column_alignment()` place to set this.

However, although `latex.add_macro()` allows one to add extra macros of various types, it shouldn't help with matrices because they already have a `_latex_()` method.  See [`src/sage/matrix/matrix0.pyx`](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/master/src/sage/matrix/matrix0.pyx#L1945).  But you could (in principle) just change the last line of this to whatever you want.

```
return "\\left" + matrix_delimiters[0] + "\\begin{array}{%s}\n"%format + s + "\n\\end{array}\\right" + matrix_delimiters[1]
```

Or perhaps even modify the rest of the code in a custom fashion as you prefer.  Alternately, you could come up with a way to make this customizable for everyone too and submit that on [Trac](https://trac.sagemath.org) - perhaps `latex.matrix_type()` where one chooses between `\matrix`, `\pmatrix`, `\array`, and friends.

I don't have a full sense of what you are suggesting in your last comment to suggest a good way to conceptualize that, though.

Comment: Thank you very much kcrisman. In my last comment, I wanted to ask whether it was possible if `matrixmacro` is any macro to replace `array` by  `matrixmacro` without creating problems.

Comment: I see.  I guess I don't know for sure; I'd have to see an example to see what you mean.  Replacing by `\matrix` probably would be okay globally (hence my suggestion) but my LaTeX knowledge doesn't extend to whether `array` and `matrix` or other things globally can take identical input.  That said, you could guarantee this would work by just hacking the `_latex_` method!

Comment: Thank you for your answers kcrisman. I will try to provide an example later if I manage to make it work.